# SonarQube - specific dashboard for projects

Tags: sonarqube

is there a way to set different main-dashboards for projects in SonarQube 5.2?

I want to see a different dashboard for project 'a' as for procect 'b'. I know there is a way to have more then one dashboard but I want to set a project-specific main dashboard.

Old Jira-Ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2486

Is it possible or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry. In fact, from 5.3 the primary project interface is standardized, and not customizable.

Comment: Okay...very sad. :/ But Thanks for answering.